# update_post_meta in loop changing ALL values

Tags: post-meta

I have a button on the frontend that updates the value of post meta on the backend, and it's nested inside a loop.

However, on submit it updates the value on ALL posts. What am I doing wrong?

```
function post_likes(){ 
global $post;
$post_id = $post->ID;
$like_value = get_post_meta($post_id, '_like_value', true);
?>
<div id="post-input-options">
    <div id="like_post">
        <form name="update_post" method="POST" action="">
            <button type="submit" name="add_like"><i class="fa fa-heart"></i></button>
        </form>
        <?php if( isset( $_POST [ 'add_like' ] ) ){
            $update = $like_value + '1';
            update_post_meta($post_id, '_like_value', $update, $like_value);
        } ?>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="post-input-info">
    <?php if( $like_value[ '_like_value' ][ '0' ] != "" ){
        echo $like_value . ' likes';
    } else {
        echo '0 likes';
    } ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Look a this code:

```
if( isset( $_POST [ 'add_like' ] ) ){
    $update = $like_value + '1';
    update_post_meta($post_id, '_like_value', $update, $like_value);
}
```

Because you're using it in a loop, it gets output multiple times on a page with a different value for `$post_id` each time. So essentially you have this:

```
if( isset( $_POST [ 'add_like' ] ) ){
    update_post_meta(1, '_like_value', $update, $like_value);
}

if( isset( $_POST [ 'add_like' ] ) ){
    update_post_meta(2, '_like_value', $update, $like_value);
}

if( isset( $_POST [ 'add_like' ] ) ){
    update_post_meta(3, '_like_value', $update, $like_value);
}
```

So consider what happens when there is a value for `$_POST [ 'add_like' ]`. All those `if`s will be `true` so every one of those updates is going to run.

Now really you should be separating the logic of handling the updating and the template. Mixing them up like this is a recipe for trouble. But the main reason your code isn't working the way you like is because your form isn't submitting *which post* to like.

You need to add a hidden input with the correct post ID, and check which post needs to be updated before updating.

So add the input to your form:

```
<form name="update_post" method="POST" action="">
    <button type="submit" name="add_like"><i class="fa fa-heart"></i></button>
    <input name="post_id" type="hidden" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $post_id ); ?>">
</form>
```

Then before updating, check that the submission was for the current post:

```
<?php if( isset( $_POST['add_like'] ) && isset( $_POST['post_id'] ) && $_POST['post_id'] === $post_id ) {
    $update = $like_value + '1';
    update_post_meta($post_id, '_like_value', $update, $like_value);
} ?>
```

Comment: Thanks. Let me apply your code...

Answer (score -1):

```php
if( isset( $_POST [ 'add_like' ] ) ){
    $update = $likes_value + '1';
    update_post_meta($post_id, '_likes_value', $update, $likes_value);
}
```

Comment: That's straight out of the code in the question that the OP says doesn't work. Can you explain what you've changed please?